# How to stop and obtain the guess of fsolve when the objective function returns NaN

Tags: matlab, nan

I am solving a system of equations using `fsolve`. Sometimes `fsolve` warns me that the objective functions return `NaN` and it tries a new point. I want to figure out how my equations deliver `NaN` with the particular guess fsolve puts in when it generates the warning. Is there a way to stop fsolve at that point and obtain the value of the guess?

I tried `dbstop if naninf`, but it doesn't help much since there are a few places in my function that generates intermediate variables that equal `NaN` or `Inf`. I am just puzzled why the equations return `NaN` in the end.

Comment: Simple. Write a new anonymous function to wrap the other function and return a bad objective function value in case of a NaN value. E.g., use g = @(x) f(x)*~isnan(x) + isnan(x)*1e+10 to wrap f(x).

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal if you have a large number of iterations, but you can set the `Display` option of `fsolve` to display the parameters after every iteration:

```
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');
[x,fval] = fsolve(@fun,x0,options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answers but they don't really solve my problem. I just came up with a simple fix: check whether the output contains `NaN`  within the function; if yes, use a global variable to retrieve the parameter values and generate an error.